# Julia DataFrame filtering based on string length

Tags: dataframe, julia

Is there a vectorized way to filter a Julia DataFrame based on the length of a string within a column?

Comment: In julia you don't need to vectorize.

Comment: Agreed. However, occasionally (and I know I'm not articulating the specific scenarios well) looping through a DataFrame can be slow.

Comment: Then maybe you should articulate the specific scenario. It seems unlikely when “looping through a DataFrame” is “slow” that vectorizing it would be any faster, unless you walk the results multiple times. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It was my assumption that vector operations were generally faster than looping. What does "walk the results" imply? Would df[df[:time] > 10,:] be as performant as looping though the column/dataframe with a conditional?

Answer (score 3):

Is the following sufficient:

```
df = DataFrame(fielda=[1,2],fieldb=["good","morning"])
df[Bool[length(x)<5 for x in df[:fieldb]],:]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(str=["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"])
df[map(str->length(str), df[:str]).<=3,:]
```

Note that there's a somewhat subtle trick here.  The following looks very similar but won't work:

```
df[map(str->length(str)<=3, df[:str]),:]
```

Because map (unlike map!) returns types of Any, which can't be used to index an array, even if they are all bools.